# Getting to debug codenameone android app on device

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to do on device debugging of my codenameone android app. I am unable to get a successful build because I am stuck with this consistent error.

```
    Android resource linking failed
/Users/jamesagada/Downloads/Ziemozi3/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1368: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/cn1Style (aka com.ziemozi:attr/attr/cn1Style)' not found.
/Users/jamesagada/Downloads/Ziemozi3/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v11/values-v11.xml:7: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/cn1Style (aka com.ziemozi:attr/attr/cn1Style)' not found.
/Users/jamesagada/Downloads/Ziemozi3/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v21/values-v21.xml:230: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/cn1Style (aka com.ziemozi:attr/attr/cn1Style)' not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Any ideas on how to get beyond this.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using? Do you have any build hints in Codename One? Did you follow the instructions here: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-debug-on-an-android-device.html did you set gradle to the external gradle process?

Comment: Android Studion 3.3.1.

Comment: I followed the instructions as best as I could. Not sure what you men by setting gradle to external gradle processor - is there an example of that? nd I did not put any special build hints. Any one I should?

Comment: Ive got this working now. I had to install build tools 27 and upgrade gradle in the gradle files.